# Trying to assign min value in vee-validate dynamically

Tags: vue.js

Vue.js component is like below.

```
<template>    
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" v-validate data-vv-rules="min:12">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['messages']        
    }
</script>
```

In the above component, `messages` property is an object with one property with value like this:

```
this.messages.Min_Length_First_Name: 3
```

I am trying to assign it like below.

```
<input type="text" 
       name="first_name" 
       v-validate 
       data-vv-rules="min:this.messages.Min_Length_First_Name">
```

But, the input tag renders the min value = `this.messages.Min_Length_First_Name` instead of numeric value

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `this` in the template. It's automatically inferred

```
  :data-vv-rules="`required|alpha|min:${messages.Min_Length_First_Name}|max:15`
```

Comment: Please note that there is backtick ` inside the quote.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please note there is backtick ` inside `data-vv-rules=""`

Comment: Can you try `:data-vv-rules`?

Comment: Can u try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55801209/failed-to-load-component-in-laravel-5-8 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778163/issue-while-trying-to-pass-json-of-translation-key-value-from-laravel-blade-to-v ?