# failed to load component in laravel 5.8

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

I have below 2 components in vue.js and using in Laravel 5.8

**Here is app.js file.**

```
require('./bootstrap');
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.use(VeeValidate);

Vue.component('profile', require('./components/Account/Profile.vue').default);
Vue.component('change-password', require('./components/Account/changepassword.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**Below is the code in change password component.**

```
<template>
    <div>

    </div>
</template>
```

When I build the code using `npm run dev`.

> I get the below error: Failed to mount component: template or render
>   function not defined in `<ChangePassword> <Root>`

When I remove the change component reference from app.js and re build using `npm run dev` then everthing work.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you lack of default in `require('./components/Account/changepassword.vue').default`?

Comment: Please, show your components code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with this `Vue.component('change-password', require('./components/Account/changepassword.vue').default);`

Instead of this:

```
Vue.component('change-password', require('./components/Account/changepassword.vue'));
```

Answer (score 0):

First your change password component is empty and then there is no export  default script that exports your component for use